# Cannot Add foreign key constraint to my table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set a FK and I am getting an error

My datatypes are same as reference table.My Artists table contain all the names and I created another table for artist images.
Tables:

[image]

```
ALTER TABLE Artist_Images
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Artist_Images_Artist
    FOREIGN KEY (Artist)
    REFERENCES Artists (Artist)
```

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Is it because Artist isnt a PK in Artists table and can't be used as PK? Any other suggestions on how can I link the tables?

Comment: Do the tables have data in them?  Are the two columns exactly the same type?

Comment: Yes Artists table has Artist multiple times and Artist_Images have distinct Artist. Datatypes are same

Comment: What is the rest of the detail with the error code?

Comment: @PaulT. I am just trying to reference a column in my Artist_Images with Artists table so I my question is how can I link without using PK in my Artists table as it can't be a PK because it has duplicate entries.

Comment: Drop the PK in the Artist_Images table, set an index (regular index, not unique) on Artist in that table instead so that it becomes a key. Then it should work. Let me know if it doesn't work, and I'll give it a try.

Comment: There could be many possible reason for getting this error `1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint` , this blog will help you for sure https://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/01/solved-how-to-solve-mysql-error-code.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reason for not being able to create a foreign key when data exists is that the column in the table you are trying to add the key to has values which do not exist in the referenced table.

In this case, you can check for that by running the following query:

```
   SELECT i.Image, i.Artist FROM Artist_Images i
      LEFT JOIN Artists a on i.Artist = a.Artist
      WHERE a.Artist IS NULL
```

If you get any rows, you need to resolve that before you can create the foreign key.